# Записать запросы в табличку базы данных

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, экранирование

Вопрос такой: создал табличку в ней поле 'text' в него хочу поместить текст запросов к этой же базе через точку с запятой. что-бы потом можно было извлекать и запускать по надобности. у запросов много разных спецсимволов, ну и это запросы в конце концов. ПХПмайадмин пробует их выполнить вместо записи.

Comment: Не смог воспроизвести. PHPMyAdmin все правильно делает. Можете пример привести?

Comment: Возможно следует заключать эти запросы в кавычки, раз они во время вставки являются текстом и не забывать при этом экранировать в них спец-символы, которые не могут просто так находится внутри строки в кавычках (те же кавычки, например)

Comment: Спасибо за идеи, вышел следующим образом: записал запросы в файл, а в табличку записал название файла, так вроде даже быстрее работает